# SomeException datatype in haskell

Tags: haskell

What is the difference between ?

```
data SomeException = forall e . Exception e => SomeException e

data SomeException = Exception e => SomeException e
```

Why do we need forall ?
[link to source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html)

Comment: By the way: do not look to the `Exception` class for a good example of how to design a class or use an existential type. It's a terrible example of both. It also fails horribly at (reliably) distinguishing the three very different concepts of imprecise exception, precise/`IO` exception, and asynchronous exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is called [Existential type](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type). The second one won't even compile.

Basically, you have to add `forall` it if you want some variable to only appear in the right-hand side (the right side of =)

It allows you e.g. to create heterogeneous list, e.g. `[SomeException]` could contain list of `SomeException e` where `e` is different for each element.

Answer (score 3):

The second variant doesn't even compile. You get:

```
error: Not in scope: type variable e
```

The reason is that it isn't clear which `e` you are referring to. You can add `e` as a type parameter on the left hand side:

```
data SomeException e = Exception e => SomeException e
```

However, this loses the point of having a `SomeException` in the first place, which is to hide the details about which concrete exception is involved. Now any function taking `SomeException e` as input would have to know about the type of `e`, again.

`forall e.` allows us to specify that we really don't care what data object is inside `SomeException` as long as it is an instance of `Exception`. That also means that we can't do anything with any `SomeException` item except for what's contained in the type class `Exception`.

You can read more about it in the [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types).